# Etimologia da palavra "aparador"

Tags: significado, etimologia

O [aparador](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aparador) é um móvel da sala de jantar no qual geralmente é guardada a louça. Não consigo no entanto associar o nome "aparador" à sua função já que este móvel aparentemente não é usado para aparar alguma coisa. Porquê a designação "aparador"?

Comment: Élio Pereira, as palavras têm muitos significados: *aparar* pode significar “Receber (o que outrem atira ou o que cai)” ou “Receber nas mãos (a criança ao nascer)”.

Comment: Não conhecia todos estes significados do verbo _aparar_. Vou assim eliminar a questão já que a resposta é na verdade óbvia.

Comment: Élio, eu te recomendo esperar!

Comment: Eu também +1. Se achas óbvio podes tu mesmo responder. Eu não acho nada óbvio que um móvel se chamasse *aparador* só por ser usado para guardar louça, ou mesmo por se lhe poder pôr em cima travessas com comida durante as refeições. Então podíamos chamar aparador a montes de coisas. Descobrir a origem dum significado particular é complicado. Mas não perdes em esperar. Eu gostava de saber mais sobre o assunto. Mais que não seja quando é essa aceção aparece.

Comment: @Jacinto tens razão. Vou manter então a questão.

Comment: Quer me parecer que estás com sorte!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essa aceção de ***aparador*** parece vir de ***aparato***. Raphael Bluteau diz assim no [Vocabulário Portuguez e Latino de 1712 (p. 417](https://books.google.pt/books?id=y4rWaU7gZfwC&pg=PA417&dq=%22Aparad%C3%B4r.%20A%20meza,%20ou%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi83aDL3Jj0AhVBVhoKHR4nAREQ6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Aparad%C3%B4r.%20A%20meza%2C%20ou%22&f=false), grafia original):

> APARADOR, Aparadôr. A meza, ou casa, em que estâ o apparato dos pratos, & vasos, de que usa a nobreza, *Vid. Copa*, que he mais portuguez.

O mesmo [Vocabulário (p. 440)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=y4rWaU7gZfwC&pg=PA440&dq=%22Appar%C3%A1to.%20Pompa%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib17ys25j0AhUN3hoKHcetBBUQ6AF6BAgEEAI#v=onepage&q=%22Appar%C3%A1to.%20Pompa%22&f=false) define:

> APPARATO, Apparáto. Pompa. Magnificencia […] A magnificencia do *Apparato*, com que lhe apresentavaõ as iguarias. Lobo, Corte na Aldea, 131.

A citação de [*Corte na Aldeia* (1619)](https://www.infopedia.pt/$corte-na-aldeia) sugere que *aparato* designava também o modo de servir uma refeição, que incluía as louças, o que está de acordo com uma das aceções dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002) — “disposição ou preparativo para qualquer festividade ou cerimónia faustosa”. Parece portanto que o móvel ganhou o nome de *aparador* por participar no aparato dos banquetes da nobreza, guardando o “aparato do pratos e vasos” (as louças finas eram uma forma de ostentar riqueza) e possivelmente servindo de mesa de apoio para os manjares e iguarias.

Isto mesmo sugere Francisco Sá de Miranda (1481 – 1558) no poema [*Malaca Conquistada*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=H_pFAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA291&lpg=PA291&dq=%22E%20dos%20Aparadores%20a%20riqueza%22&source=bl&ots=9SVWhzsEgV&sig=ACfU3U0KAbV8SFDXQ8iOZCvthUIYf6afFg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjd-b7A1pj0AhXxyYUKHa9jCLkQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=onepage&q=%22E%20dos%20Aparadores%20a%20riqueza%22&f=false) (grafia atualizada, negrito meu; esta aceção é portano já bastante antiga):

> Excedia da casa o ilustre ornato,
> E **dos aparadores a riqueza**,
> A fragância, do Céu quase retrato,
> E do trato político a estranheza;
> Era igual em **magnífico aparato**
> No modo, no concerto, na grandeza
> Ao **grão banquete** das histórias digno
> Da bela egípcia ao vencedor latino